# Need assistance with basic Java program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Sorry for bothering you guys, I'm new to programming and have been having problems with this program.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Project13{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        String heightStr;
        String weightStr;
        int height;
        int weight;
        int bmi;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");

        heightStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter height in centimetres:");
        height = Integer.parseInt(heightStr);

        weightStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter weight in kilograms:");
        weight = Integer.parseInt(weightStr);

        int bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The BMI is "+ bmi +" .");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I receive the following error messages:

> Project3_3.java:24: error: variable bmi is already defined in method main(String[])
>               int bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));
>
> Project3_3.java:24: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
>               int bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));

Can anyone spot the problem?

Also, what program would be the best to write Java in? I currently use Crimson Editor, however, it requires a lot of setup every time I use it.

Thanks!

*******EDIT***************
I removed the int from BMI, and the lossy conversion error still persists. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: For the first you cannot declare an identifier more than once in the same scope. For the second you are putting a double value into an int variable, there are many doubles that cannot be coverted unchanged into ints the compiler is warning you about that.

Comment: post edit: declare bmi as a 'double' rather than an 'int'.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
int bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));
```

You already declared bmi along with the other variables. You should set bmi instead.

```
bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0)); //take out the "int"
```

Comment: Also, as BevynQ mentioned, the value you're trying to pass into bmi is a double since there's a decimal, so you should declare bmi as type double instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

the first error is caused by this line:
`int bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));` replace it by:
`bmi = weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));`

the second one is actually a warning: the value created by `weight/ ((height/ 100.0)* (height/ 100.0));` is of type `double` and is assigned to a variable of type `int`. simply add a cast to int to prevent this warning from appearing.

For the second part of the question: this is rather depending upon what you want. IDE or Editor, etc. . I personally use IntelliJ (pretty powerful autocompletion), another popular IDE is eclipse, thats really dependant upon what you want.

Comment: yup, thats how you cast a value to inttype